# Force meta data on specific product type

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, seo, noindex, nofollow

I'm working on a Woocommerce website were I have multiple product types: simple_product, enviso_group_offer and enviso_group_ticket. All of these types are just products in my Woocommerce.

No I want to add the noindex, nofollow meta tag to only the **enviso_group_ticket** products.

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex,nofollow”/>
```

How can I achieve that? When I'm using the SEO plugin Yoast, I can only target all the Products, instead of a specific product type.

At this moment, I've done it with the following code, but I feels not the right way to do so:

```
$product_type = get_the_terms( $product_id,'product_type')[0]->slug;

if($product_type == "enviso_group_ticket") {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('head').append('<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex,nofollow”/>');
        })
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Can this be done with a Wordpress hook? Or should it be done differently?
I know that I can achieve it by adding the noindex and nofollow on every enviso_group_ticket manually, but I want to force it automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) hook:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'check_for_enviso_group_ticket' );
function check_for_enviso_group_ticket() {
    if ( is_product() && ( 'enviso_group_ticket' == get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_type' )[0]->slug ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

or to not break your site in case the WooCommerce is disabled and the `is_product()` function isn't defined:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'check_for_enviso_group_ticket' );
function check_for_enviso_group_ticket() {
    if ( is_singular( array( 'product' ) ) && ( 'enviso_group_ticket' == get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_type' )[0]->slug ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```